# Not able to pass data from view to controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

View code, a function to create an array of data and then pass it to the controller via AJAX:

```
function jobsheet_save() {
    // array for parts
    var parts = new Array(c);

    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
        parts[i] = new Array(4);

    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        parts[i][0] = $('#textbox' + (i+1)).val();
        parts[i][1] = $('#pd' + (i+1)).val();
        parts[i][2] = $('#pq' + (i+1)).val();
        parts[i][3] = $('#pa' + (i+1)).val();   
    }

    var jformdata = new Array();

    // array for form  
    var jid = $('#jobsheetid').val();
    var jregdate = $('#regdate').val();
    var jregby = $('#regby').val();
    var jsource = $('#source').val();
    var jcompdate = $('#completiondate').val();
    var jdeldate = $('#deliverydate').val();
    var jjcustid = $('#jcustomerId').val();
    var jcustname = $('#jcustomername').val();
    var jcustadd = $('#jaddress1').val();
    var jcustphone = $('#jphone1').val();
    var jcustemail = $('#jemail').val();
    var jproducttype = $('#jproducttype').val();
    var jproductname = $('#jproductname').val();
    var jproductmodel = $('#pmodel').val();
    var jproductserial = $('#pserialno').val();
    var jproductsubcat = $('#pscat').val();
    var jproductwarranty = $('#pwarranty').val();
    var jproductcondition = $('#pcondition').val();
    var jproductcomplaint = $('#jproductcomplaint').val();
    var jproductcomptype = $('#jcomplainttype').val();
    var jproductpurdate = $('#pdate').val();
    var jdealername = $('#jdealername').val();
    var jdealerphone = $('#jdealerphone').val();
    var jcallallocdate = $('#jcallallocdate').val();
    var jcallalloctime = $('#jcallalloctime').val();
    var jvisitdate = $('#visitdate').val();
    var jvisitdetails = $('#visitdetails').val();
    var jengname = $('#engname').val();
    var jrepairremarks = $('#repairremarks').val();

    // insert variable values into array
    jformdata[0] = jid;
    jformdata[1] = jregdate;
    jformdata[2] = jregby;
    jformdata[3] = jsource;
    jformdata[4] = jcompdate;
    jformdata[5] = jdeldate;
    jformdata[6] = jjcustid;
    jformdata[7] = jcustname;
    jformdata[8] = jcustadd;
    jformdata[9] = jcustphone;
    jformdata[10] = jproducttype;
    jformdata[11] = jproductname;
    jformdata[12] = jproductmodel;
    jformdata[13] = jproductserial;
    jformdata[14] = jproductsubcat;
    jformdata[15] = jproductwarranty;
    jformdata[16] = jproductcondition;
    jformdata[17] = jproductcomplaint;
    jformdata[18] = jproductcomptype;
    jformdata[19] = jproductpurdate;
    jformdata[20] = jdealername;
    jformdata[21] = jdealerphone;
    jformdata[22] = jcallallocdate;
    jformdata[23] = jcallalloctime;
    jformdata[24] = jvisitdate;
    jformdata[25] = jvisitdetails;
    jformdata[26] = jengname;
    jformdata[27] = jrepairremarks;

    alert(jformdata);
    // ajax adding data to database
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('jobsheet_controller/add_data')?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: ({
            jfdata: jformdata
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            alert("aala r");
            if (data.status) { // if success close modal and reload ajax table
                $('#modal_jobsheet').modal('hide');
                reload_table();
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) {
                    $('[name="' + data.inputerror[i] + '"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add has-error class
                    $('[name="' + data.inputerror[i] + '"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); //select span help-block class set text error string
                }
            }
            $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
            $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', false); //set button enable 
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error adding / update data');
            $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
            $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', false); //set button enable 
        }
    });
}
```

This is the controller code to accept data from the view and then pass it to the model:

```
public function add_data() {
    $dealercode = $this->session->userdata('userid');
    $did = $dealercode['dealercode'];
    $data = $this->input->post('jfdata');
    $data3 = array(
        'jobsheetid' => $data[0],
        'regdate' => $data[1],
        'regby' => $data[2],
        'source' => $data[3],
        'completiondate' => $data[4],
        'deliverydate' => $data[5],
        'customerId' => $data[6],
        'customername' => $data[7],
        'customeraddress' => $data[8],
        'customerphone' => $data[9],
        'producttype'=> $data[10],
        'productname' => $data[11],
        'productmodel' => $data[12],
        'productserial' => $data[13],
        'subcategory' => $data[14],
        'warranty' => $data[15],
        'productcondition' => $data[16],
        'complaint' => $data[17],
        'complainttype' => $data[18],
        'purchasedate' => $data[19],
        'dealername' => $data[20],
        'dealerphone'=> $data[21],
        'callallocdate' => $data[22],
        'callalloctime' => $data[23],
        'visitdate' => $data[24],
        'visitdetail' => $data[25],
        'engname' => $data[26],
        'repairremark' => $data[27],
        'servicecharges' => $data[28],
        'dealercode' => $did
    );

    // Save data to customerMaster
    $insert = $this->jobsheet->save($data3);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
```

This is the model code, a function to send data to database:

```
public function save($data) {
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: try `data:{jfdata: jformdata},` in your ajax query (I removed the "()"). [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Maybe you need to receive the data like this: `$variable = json_decode($_POST["jfdata"]);`

Comment: tried all above still not working.

Comment: you need more variables man,these are not nearly enough :)))

Comment: well i wonder if that could be the solution :(

Comment: do you know what a array key is?

Comment: where do you use the parts variable?

Comment: currently m not using parts variable ... its value will be inserted to other table. m only passing jformdata

Answer (score 0):

add datatype in ajax function as 'json' or 'html'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
data: ({
 jfdata: jformdata
 })
```

change into this

```
data:{
 jfdata: jformdata
 }
```

Comment: by not woking what do you mean?

Comment: you mean your ajax isn't triggering, you mean you have 404 ajax error,you mean you have a 500eror, you mean you have console erors, what exacly is this "not working"